# How to store open state of particular ChildWindow in a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, childwindow

I use ChildWindows in my project and I need to store ***open state*** of particular ChildWindow  in a property, then use that property as a condition for mentioned ChildWindow calling.

First I made this snippet of code. It has its drawbacks. So I want to use another way.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (ChildWindow_02_in_XAML.IsOpen == false)

        {
            // await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new ChildWindow_02() { IsModal = false, AllowMove = true, }, RootGrid);
            Parameter_02_in_XAML.IsOpen = true;

        }

        else if (Parameter_02_in_XAML.IsOpen == true)

        {

            Parameter_02_in_XAML.Close();

        }

       else 

        {

            return;

        }

    }
```

Now I have ChildWindow as a class, and I made following stuff:

```
 IsOpen="{Binding IschildWindow_02_Opened}"
```

And I'm going to use that method that is commented at the moment.

So I have a question how to process with this variable further.

Comment: Are you using MVVM? More info is needed. What have you tried?

Comment: No, I don't use MVVM.